# Include Image Data in JSON FabricJS

Tags: javascript, json, fabricjs

I'm trying to use FabricJS canvas, and I'd like to export canvas as JSON.

I've tried loading image using both `new fabric.Image` and `fabric.Image.fromURL` both of them work great.

Now I want to get JSON from canvas. But I want 2 kinds of JSON. One where image's src would be link to a image which I used initially. Another would simply add base64 data right on JSON. So I tried to use `canvas.toJSON()` and `canvas.toDatalessJSON()`, but to my surprise, It simply gives same result with link, and none of them contain image data.

How do I export to JSON which INCLUDES image data right on JSON? (I already got with the link)

I've put together a small [demo](http://jsbin.com/bunosaduwi/edit?js,console,output) of what I have till now. Notice when you click on export and see on console, both objects have source link and none of them actually have base64 data.

The reason I want base64 is because I want it instant when I re-use somewhere else.

I tried searching over the internet, according to docs, toJSON should contain, but looks like it's only for shapes, and not image. Or did I miss something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extend toObject of fabric.Image

```
fabric.Image.prototype.toObject = (function(toObject) {
  return function() {
    return fabric.util.object.extend(toObject.call(this), {
      src: this.toDataURL()
    });
  };
})(fabric.Image.prototype.toObject);
```

And for src use `object.toDataURL()`

***DEMO***

```js
const useFabricImage = () => {
  const c = document.getElementById("designer");
  const canvas = new fabric.Canvas(c, {width: 500, height: 500})
  const url = "https://i.imgur.com/KxijB.jpg";
  const img = new Image();
  img.src = url;
  const fabricImage = new fabric.Image(img, {});
  canvas.add(fabricImage);
  
  return canvas;
}
const useFromURL = () => {
  const c = document.getElementById("designer");
  const canvas = new fabric.Canvas(c, {width: 500, height: 500})
  const url = "https://i.imgur.com/KxijB.jpg";
  fabric.Image.fromURL(url, (img) => {
    canvas.add(img);
  },{
    crossOrigin:'annonymous'
  });
  return canvas;
}
fabric.Image.prototype.toDatalessObject = fabric.Image.prototype.toObject;

fabric.Image.prototype.toObject = (function(toObject) {
  return function() {
    return fabric.util.object.extend(toObject.call(this), {
      src: this.toDataURL()
    });
  };
})(fabric.Image.prototype.toObject);


const canvas = useFromURL();

const button = document.getElementById("export");
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log(canvas.toJSON());
  console.log(canvas.toDatalessJSON());
})
```

```css
#designer {
  border: 1px solid aqua;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.3.3/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="designer" height="500" width="500"></canvas>
<button id="export">Export</button>
```

Comment: This one does work, but it breaks the toDatalessJSON, basically it adds data to both methods which is not what I wanted, toDatalessJSON should have link to image, and toJSON should have all data.

Comment: I needed to include custom properties, added the parameter to `function()` -> `function(propertiesToInclude)` and added the parameter to the "call": `toObject.call(this, propertiesToInclude)`

Comment: Hi thanks it worked but is there a way we can remove orientation details from base64 string

Comment: i'm getting issue while loading json, images rotated twice, on with object position and other the actual image(base64)

Answer (score 1):

You need to extend `fabric.Image.protype.toObject()`:

```js
fabric.Image.prototype.toObject = (function (toObject) {

    return function () {
        var image = this;

        var getData = function () {
            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvas.width = image.width;
            canvas.height = image.height;

            context = canvas.getContext('2d');

            context.drawImage(image.getElement(), 0, 0);

            return canvas.toDataURL('image/png').replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, '');
        };

        return fabric.util.object.extend(toObject.call(this), {
            dataURL: getData(),
        });
    };
})(fabric.Image.prototype.toObject);
```

After that `dataURL` property will be automatically added to your object.