# Save State of Canvas in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, draw

I am implementing Draw function, to draw a line in canvas. The Draw function is activated on the first double click and on mouse move the line is being drawn and on the second double click, the draw function is deactivated.
When I double click the third time the previously drawn line is disappearing. My requirement is I want to retain all of the lines. How do I do that?
Below is my draw function:

```
handleMouseMove(event){
        if(this.state.isDouble)
        {

            this.Draw(event)
        }
        else{

        }
    }
 Draw(event){


        x2=event.offsetX
        y2=event.offsetY
        const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        ctx.lineWidth = 3;
        //Deleting The State
        ctx.canvas.width = ctx.canvas.width;


        console.log("First" + this.state.previousPointX,this.state.previousPointY)
        console.log("Second" + x2,y2)
        xtemp=x2
        ytemp=this.state.previousPointY


        console.log("Temp" + xtemp,ytemp)
        ctx.beginPath()

        ctx.moveTo(xtemp,ytemp);
        ctx.lineTo(x2,y2);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.moveTo(xtemp,ytemp);
        ctx.lineTo(this.state.previousPointX,this.state.previousPointY);
        ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
        ctx.stroke();
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51434198/include-image-data-in-json-fabricjs) that you can save the canvas by converting it to json
for Redux store, I have tested using state for my Fabric canvas instance, its a 3rd party library that is a wrapper on a HTML canvas DOM element.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './WallToDecorate.css';
import { fabric } from 'fabric';

const WallToDecorate = ({templateList=[]}) => {

  const [wallCanvas, setCanvas] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {


const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('fabric-canvas-to-decorate', {
    width: rect.width,
    height: rect.height
  });


canvas.setBackgroundImage(
  originalWallImage.src,
  canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
  {
    backgroundImageOpacity: 1,
    backgroundImageStretch: false,

    top: top,
    left: left,
  }
);

setCanvas(canvas);
  }, []);

  const addImageToCanvas = (event) => {

    fabric.util.loadImage(
      event.target.src,
      function (img) {
        var fab_image = new fabric.Image(img, {
        });
        wallCanvas.add(fab_image);
        wallCanvas.renderAll();
      },
      { left: 100, top: 100, angle: 0, opacity: 1 }
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div id="select-image-dimensions" className="placeholder canvas-size">
        <canvas id="fabric-canvas-to-decorate" />
      </div>
             </>
  );
}

export default WallToDecorate;
```

In my case the `wallCanvas.renderAll()` refreshes the canvas element.